# Can't Use Hammer Editor Grid or 3d Camera

Tags: source-engine, hammer

I can't place anything (tried Shift + R) and it shows two white lines making a right angle when I open a map. I can't edit my maps currently. Can anyone help? An alternative to editing maps?

[image]

Only ray-traced works for 3D:

[image]

Comment: It's pretty difficult to tell why you're having this problem. Has it worked before? What's changed? What have you tried to solve the problem? Reinstall? Restart?

Comment: Remember to search first and post second.  This thread was the 2nd result, and has a few suggestions for you.  Good luck.  http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2493261

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly the Source SDK went bonkers when Steam implemented [SteamPipe](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamPipe). I have tried it myself and I frequently get a pop-up error saying:

"Failed to load the default scheme file. The map view may be missing some visual elements."

All of the view ports in the ui are blank and I can't interact with them at all. I'll do some more research into it and comment on this if I find a fix anywhere.

Comment: If you're receiving the same error message as me, check out this page: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Failed_to_load_the_default_scheme_file